# How do I use FileTemplate as a substitute for Splice to export Mathematica expressions into Fortran?

Tags: fortran, wolfram-mathematica, splice

I found the Splice functionality in Mathematica quite useful in the past.  I am trying to insert mathematica expressions, formatted for Fortran, into Fotran code.

Does anyone have a small working example they would be willing to share?  Thanks.

I could write  Mathematica code

```
y=x^3
```

and construct a file test.fm with

```
      program test
      real x,y
      x=1.0
      y=
     -  <* y *>
      write(6,*) "y",y
      end
```

and the mathematica line
Splice["test.fm"]
would give a file test.f with

```
      program test 
      real x,y
      x=1.0
      y=
     - x**3
      write(6,*) "y",y
      end
```

Apparently this use of Splice is removed in recent Mathematica releases, and I get an error message

```
  The function Splice with filename inputs is now obsolete and has been
    superseded by FileTemplate.
```

I tried

```
FileTemplate["test.mf"]
```

but it returns something that apparently needs further output.  I then tried

```
TemplateApply[FileTemplate["my.fm"]]
```

but this didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Make sure that your posts are properly formatted (see my edits). When you face an error message, always copy the exact error message. Formulations like "something that apparently needs further output" or "didn't work either" are unclear and do not say much useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileTemplate` yields a `TemplateObject` expression that you need to apply. Here is an example application using your code and `StringTemplate`, which similarly yields a `TemplateObject` expression.

```
Clear[x]
y = x^3
StringTemplate["      program test
      real x,y
      x=1.0
      y=
     -  <* y *>
      write(6,*) \"y\",y
      end", InsertionFunction -> ToString@*FortranForm][<|"y" -> y|>]
```

Comment: Dear Alan, thanks for your answer.  What is the easiest way to dump StringTemplate to a file?  Dear Vladimir, thanks for your edits.

Comment: @JohnKolassa Does that phrasing capture the question you meant to ask? The point of my answer is that you can use `FileTemplate` as you did but you need to apply it as I illustrated with `StringTemplate`. (I used `StringTemplate` instead of `FileTemplate` only to produce a self-contained illustration.) The result of applying the resulting `TemplateObject` is a string in either case. You can export it like any other string.

Comment: Thanks to Alan for your help.  This answered the question I asked, and got me most of the way to the solution to my problem.  The code I generate is inconvenient, in that Fortran line lengths exceed the standard.  I have been getting around this by using a compiler flag to override line length, but it would be more convenient to output code with Mathematica breaking the lines, and including appropriate continuation characters (f77 or f90 standard, it doesn't matter which to me.)

Comment: @JohnKolassa Does the `PageWidth` option do this? (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: Thanks.  I saw this option, but didn't know how to add it to the ToString function call above.  John

Comment: @JohnKolassa I think you have already chosen the best approach, but you could try replacing `ToString@*FortranForm` with `Composition[ToString,FortranForm[#,PageWidth->78]&]`.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate your time and expertise.  Let me try.  John